# Transitive dependency involving more than 3 attributes

Tags: database-design, functional-dependencies, transitive-dependency

Given the following set of function dependencies

```
A -> B 
B -> C
B -/> A     (B doesn't functionally determine A)
```

if A->C exist, it is a transitive dependency

What if we are given the following 2 situations, are they transitive dependency too?

### First situation

```
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D
B -/> A
C -/> B
```

is A->D a transitive dependency?

### Second situation

```
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D
B -/> A
C -> B
```

is A->D a transitive dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is trivial. You don't even need to clarify when something is NOT a TD. It is assumed that nothing is a TD but the TDs you explicitly define. So the first step is to remove the redundancy of all

```
X -/> Y
```

Now, given:

```
A -> B
B -> C
C -> D
```

The following are transitive dependencies:

```
A -> C
A -> D
B -> D
```

Adding any other dependencies won't change the current transitive dependencies

Comment: Thanks! That's for the first situation, what about the second situation? is A->D a transitive dependency too?

Comment: Actually, that covers both situations, because they happen to be the same. As I mentioned in the last comment, `adding any other dependencies (such as C -> B) won't change the current TDs`.